# LDAP schema for User Account for login

Tags: spring-security, ldap, openldap, spring-ldap

I am new to LDAP trying to create schema for User authentication Purpose. `DN: uid=55e44a75e4b0f16711714165,ou=people,dc=myDB,dc=com`

Every thing is perfect I can add data like cn=Prashant, sn= thorat ,mail=xx@gmail.com,mobile:xxxxx , password=xxxx . And I can Authenticate user using mail and password.

Now I want to mark status here as deleted . So that on login I can Identify User status from LDAP. Is their any attribute or Object to add user status as deleted / active or need to create custom.

ref: http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ape/#contents

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense. If you're really creating your own schema there is nothing stopping you from adding your own `deleted` attribute. I conclude that you aren't creating a schema at all, you are deploying an existing one.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `deleted` attribute in any LDAP schema I am aware of. You could use the `pwdAccountLockedTime` attribute of the password-policy overlay: set it to `000001010000Z`. See [here](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ape/ppolicy.html). If you did that you would also have to use the password-policy response control when binding.